# CSS3 animation doesn't work in Safari or IE

Tags: javascript, css

Here is the pastebin link so you can easily see what's going on http://pastebin.com/jGQk2JJ8 It's probably quite an easy problem to solve.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to write the vendor-specific properties first followed by the unprefixed property. I.e. for your `.loaded` selector that would be: `-webkit-transform: translateX(0px); transform: translateX(0px);`. For supplier in IE9+ you need to add `-ms-transform: translateX(0px)`.

Comment: I've done that and it's made 0 difference

Answer (score 0):

You can always check first the browser support first.

As it seems, safari browser supports in general the CSS3 animation events, but not all versions do as well.

Check [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) and compare it with your version of safari.

Comment: It doesn't work on IE either so it's not a version problem, it's a problem with the javascript.

Comment: First of all for IE support you have to use the prefix -ms- . IE is not a webkit browser. Safari is a webkit browser? Is this working normally on Chrome?

Comment: Yeah I've added the -ms- but still the same problem, Yes it's working in chrome and firefox...........like I said it's nothing to do with the CSS

Comment: I've updated the js file too in attempts to fix the issue http://pastebin.com/b09MeHv4

Comment: The truth is that a jFiddle would be better aid to us. The code you provide is not enough to create one.